# Why Is Doppl Trying To Pull in ReactiveStreams?

Tags: doppl

I am attempting to convert parts of an Android app to iOS using Doppl, and I am getting a strange result: Doppl keeps trying to pull in `android.arch.lifecycle:reactivestreams`, even though I don't want it to.

Specifically, in `app/build/j2objcSrcGenMain/android/arch/lifecycle/`, there is a `reactivestrams/` subdirectory with `R.h` and `R.m` files in it. This seems to make Xcode cranky and may explain why I had some oddities with `pod install`.

My `app/build.gradle` has `compile "android.arch.lifecycle:reactivestreams:$archVer"`, because my activity is using `LiveDataReactiveStreams.fromPublisher()`. However:

- The activity is not in the `translatePattern` (and since its code is not showing up in `app/build/j2objcSrcGenMain/`, I have to assume that the `translatePattern` is fine)
- I do not have a `doppl` statement related to `reactivestreams`, because there does not appear to be a Doppl conversion of this library (nor should it be needed here)
- AFAIK, nowhere else in this app am I referring to `LiveDataReactiveStreams`, which AFAIK is the one-and-only `public` class from the `reactivestreams` library

So, the questions:

1. What determines whether Doppl creates `R.h` and `R.m` files for some dependency? It's not the existence of a `doppl` statement, as I have `doppl` statements for a lot of other dependencies (RxJava, RxAndroid, Retrofit) and those do not get `R.h` and `R.m` files. It's not whether the dependency is referenced from generated code, as my repository definitely uses RxJava and Retrofit, yet there are no `R` files for those.
2. How can I figure out why Doppl generates `R.h` and `R.m` for `reactivestreams`?
3. Once I get this cleared up... do I re-run `pod install`, or is there some other `pod` command to refresh an existing pod with a new implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I screwed up.

In my `dopplConfig`, I have:

```
  translatePattern {
    include '**/api/**'
    include '**/arch/**'
    include '**/RepositoryTest.java'
  }
```

In this case, `**/arch/**` not only matches *my* `arch` package, but also the `arch` package from the Architecture Components.

Ordinarily, this would not matter, because the Architecture Components source code is not in my project. But, `R.java` gets generated, due to resources, and the `translatePattern` includes generated source code in addition to lovingly hand-crafted source code. So, that's where my extraneous Objective-C was coming from.

Many thanks to Kevin Galligan for his assistance with this, out on [the #newbiehelp Doppl Slack channel](http://doppl.co/docs/Support.html)!

Answer (score 1):

Look into 'app/build/generated/source/r/debug' and confirm there's an R.java being created for the architecture component. It'll be under 'android/arch/lifecycle/reactivestrams'.

I think there are 2 problems here.

*Problem 1*

Somehow Doppl/J2objc is of the opinion that this file should be transpiled. It could be either that 'translatePattern' matches with it, or that something in the shared code is referencing it. If you can't figure out which, please post a comment and I'll try to help (or post in slack group).

*Problem 2*

Regardless of *why* that 'R.java' is being sucked into the translate step, because of how stock J2objc is configured, the code is being generated with package folders instead of creating One Big Name. That generated file should be called 'AndroidArchLifecycleReactivestramsR.h' (and AndroidArchLifecycleReactivestramsR.m). Xcode really doesn't like package folders. That's why there's a slightly custom J2ojbc being used with Doppl, so we can have files with big names instead of folders.

In cases where you *intentionally* use package names that match with what J2objc considers to be "system" classes, you need to provide a header mapping file to force long names. The 'androidbase' doppl library needs to add a lot of files that are in the 'android' package, which J2objc considers "system". We override those names in the mapping file.

build.gradle
https://github.com/doppllib/core-doppl/blob/master/androidbase/build.gradle#L19

mapping file
https://github.com/doppllib/core-doppl/blob/master/androidbase/src/main/java/androidbase.mappings

Comment: "confirm there's an R.java being created for the architecture component" -- yes, it's there. "It could be either that 'translatePattern' matches with it, or that something in the shared code is referencing it" -- `LiveDataReactiveStreams` is only referenced in `MainActivity`. `MainActivity` does not match the `translatePattern`, as it does not get translated.